# Get the ratio of translation in a Django (or Python) project

Tags: python, django, continuous-integration, internationalization

Is there a simple way to get the ratio of translated messages in a Django project or by default in a Python project containing .po files?

I have seen the Polib library API has a function to do that (https://polib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#polib.POFile.percent_translated) but it there and easy way to do this with adding this lib and make a script for the CI-check?